# Include UTF8 file in ASCII file

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

In the project I'm working there are lots of ASCII files. A file that is included in all files needs to be UTF8 in order to work properly.

What problems I might face if I include an UTF8 file in ASCII and visa versa?

```
include 'x.php'
```

*I couldn't find any free tool to convert files to UTF8 encoding in bulk, for windows.*

**Edit: x.php have a function to convert utf8 text to ascii. ascii encoded php files includes x.php and use the function.**

Comment: "Include" how exactly? And since ASCII is a pure subset of UTF-8, there's no incompatibility as such. It depends what you do with the rest though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pure 7-bit ASCII file is an exact subset of UTF-8 (note that doesn't hold true for extended 8-bit ASCII). If you mix ASCII and UTF-8 files, the result will all be valid UTF-8. If you tried to convert ASCII to UTF-8, you'd end up with the same ASCII file; it's already valid UTF-8.

As long as whatever you're doing with those files handles UTF-8 correctly, you're already handling ASCII correctly as well.

You may want to read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: Thanks. "x.php have a function to convert utf8 text to ascii. ascii encoded php files includes x.php and use the function." So, it should work. Am I correct?

Comment: How does one "convert UTF-8 to ASCII" exactly?

Comment: `$q = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $q);`

Comment: I'm really not sure what the purpose of this is or what this really has to do with "including a UTF-8 file in ASCII"...